# query for select chat and last message

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables in the database. One of tables is for chats, and another one is for messages. Every chat has an id and also every message has its chat id. I used a join query to select all chats of specific user and last message, but I can't set limit for messages table.
this is my query:

```
SELECT id, name, host, client, closed, chats.attach, response, message, messages.time 
FROM chats 
INNER JOIN messages ON chat_id = id 
WHERE chats.client = ? OR chats.host = ? 
ORDER BY messages.time DESC
```

I want a query that returns a user chats with the last message.

Comment: So you want all the user's chats but with only the latest message from each one, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the below query the query will retrieve messages and chats. With subquery the most recent message for each chat is returned and also the subquery is combined with chat details. The result can be seen with where clause which is used as a filter.

```
SELECT chats.id, chats.name, chats.host, chats.client, chats.closed, chats.attach, messages.response, messages.message, messages.time
FROM chats
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT chat_id, response, message, time
    FROM messages
    WHERE chat_id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM chats
        WHERE client = ? OR host = ?
    )
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS messages ON chats.id = messages.chat_id
WHERE chats.client = ? OR chats.host = ?
```

Comment: A better answer, more likely to attract votes, would provide some explanation of what you've done and why. A code dump by itself usually isn't all that helpful. See also [answer]. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson thanks for letting me know rules which will be helpful to me while answwering.

Comment: No problem. You can [edit] your answer whenever you like.